# AppComponent app.component.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules? But modules are server side and client side module?

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, asp.net-core

We have a shared const file that imports all of the components for out application, and two separate app modules for server side pre-rendering as posted below:

Debug works fine, but in release we get this error on this webpack command:

"node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod"

"ERROR in Type AppComponent app.component.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in app.module.client.ts and AppModule in app.module.server.ts! Please consider moving AppComponent in app.component.ts to a higher module that imports AppModule in app.module.client.ts and AppModule in app.module.server.ts. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes AppComponent in app.component.ts then import that NgModule in AppModule in app.module.client.ts and AppModule in app.module.server.ts."

I know it has to do with declaring my components twice from the Shared file, but if I make the shared a module, and import it to server and client, the build breaks at runtime because it can't discern the angular components for some reason. I'm still learning with angular 4 so can someone help with how I am supposed to correctly set up a shared module into a server side and client side app module for a publish build?

app.module.shared.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ButtonsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons';
import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
import { SliderModule, SwitchModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-inputs';
import { TabStripModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-layout';
import { AutoCompleteModule, DropDownListModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';
import { DateInputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs';
import { InputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-inputs';

import { MonacoEditorComponent } from './components/monaco-editor/monaco-editor.component';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { ClientsComponent } from './components/clients/clients.component';
import { EditConfigComponent } from './components/edit-config/edit-config.component';
import { AddClientComponent } from './components/add-client/add-client.component';
import { AddIntegrationComponent } from './components/add-integration/add-integration.component';
import { MsgInfoComponent } from './components/msg-info/msg-info.component';
import { AppFooterComponent } from './components/app-footer/app-footer.component';

import { ClientIntegrationService } from './client-integration.service';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { User } from './user';
import { Roles } from './roles';

import { RoleGuard } from './guards/role-guard';
import { ClientConfigurationGuard } from './guards/client-configuration-guard';
import { BaseMappingGuard } from './guards/base-mapping-guard';
import { AddIntegrationGuard } from './guards/add-integration-guard';
import { EditUserGuard } from './guards/edit-user-guard';



export const sharedConfig: NgModule = {
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        ClientsComponent,
        EditConfigComponent,
        AddClientComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        AppRoutingModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        ButtonsModule,
        GridModule,
        SliderModule,
        TabStripModule,
        AutoCompleteModule,
        DropDownListModule,
        SwitchModule,
        DateInputsModule,
        InputsModule
    ],
    providers: [ClientIntegrationService,
        UserService,
        User,
        RoleGuard,
        ClientConfigurationGuard,
        BaseMappingGuard,
        AddIntegrationGuard,
        EditUserGuard
    ]
};
```

app.module.client.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
import { bootloader } from '@angularclass/bootloader';
import { sharedConfig } from './app.module.shared';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';


@NgModule({
    bootstrap: sharedConfig.bootstrap,
    declarations: [sharedConfig.declarations],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        GridModule,
        ...sharedConfig.imports
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin },
        sharedConfig.providers
    ]
})
export class AppModule{
}

export const platformRef = platformBrowserDynamic();

export function main() {
    return platformRef.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
}

bootloader(main);
```

app.module.server.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { sharedConfig } from './app.module.shared';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: sharedConfig.bootstrap,
    declarations: sharedConfig.declarations,
    imports: [
        ServerModule,
        NoopAnimationsModule,
        ...sharedConfig.imports
    ],
    providers: sharedConfig.providers
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem comes basically from the `[sharedConfig.declarations]` part. It seems like an unusual way of implementing `Server` and `Client` modules. Have you tried having the declarations only on your `AppModule`? (what you declared in `app.module.client.ts`.

If it helps, here is my standard implementation using three different modules (`AppModule`, `BrowserAppModule` and `ServerAppModule`). I basically just declare everything on my `AppModule` and then simply import that module into the other two, along with whatever they each need. None of them declares anything, but both bootstrap the `AppComponent`.

---

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        AppRoutingModule,
        CommonModule,
        SharedModule
    ],
    providers: [
        MyCustomService
    ],
    exports: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

browser.app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppModule
    ]
})
export class BrowserAppModule {
}
```

server.app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        ServerModule,
        AppModule
    ]
})
export class ServerAppModule {
}
```